# VSCode Multiple-Folder Workspace Search references

Tags: visual-studio-code

Going through a project that start to be quite huge, we've got a workspace with 10+ folders.

Into those 10+ folders we have 9 folders that have the same code base in Node.js & the 10th one that is a private NPM package that we build and that all 9 others rely on.

We're trying to make things easier for all the devs to find some other usage of a function they want to explore and for that, we wanted to be able to find some function references / implementations across all the folders of the workspace.

For instance, if I go in one of the folder, in one of the source file :

[image]

and I right-click on the authorize method that is custom and implemented into the NPM private package. If I look up for References I'll get results like this :

[image]

But those are only the result of the reference of this method into this folder and not into others project that also use this express middleware.

You can see that I also get the result of the dist folder of the NPM package which seems logical but also seems to be the problem that I am facing.

I don't really know what can also be useful so feel free to ask me any kind of content and find attached the workspace configuration :

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "name": "Docs",
      "path": "./repositories/Docs"
    },
    {
      "name": "Frontend",
      "path": "./repositories/project_pwa"
    },
    {
      "name": "Service A",
      "path": "./repositories/project_A"
    },
    {
      "name": "Service B",
      "path": "./repositories/project_B"
    },
    {
      "name": "Project C",
      "path": "./repositories/project_C"
    },
    {
      "name": "Project D",
      "path": "./repositories/project_D"
    },
    {
      "name": "Project E",
      "path": "./repositories/project_E"
    },
    {
      "name": "Project F",
      "path": "./repositories/project_F"
    },
    {
      "name": "Project G",
      "path": "./repositories/project_G"
    },
    {
      "name": "Project H",
      "path": "./repositories/project_H"
    },
    {
      "name": "project I",
      "path": "./repositories/project_I"
    },
    {
      "name": "Project J",
      "path": "./repositories/project_J"
    },
    {
      "name": "Project K",
      "path": "./repositories/project_K"
    },
    {
      "path": "./repositories/project_L",
      "name": "Project L"
    },
    {
      "path": ".",
      "name": "Master"
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "markdown.extension.print.imgToBase64": true,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "alt",
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "boundary",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "markdown.extension.print.absoluteImgPath": false,
    "markdown.extension.print.validateUrls": false,
    "markdown.extension.toc.levels": "2..6",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "files.exclude": {
      "node_modules": true,
      "dist": true,
      "repositories": true
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
    "[javascript]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
    },
    "[jsonc]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    },
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
  },
  "extensions": {
    "recommendations": [
      "yzhang.markdown-all-in-one",
      "stamminger.vscode-markdown-preview-include",
      "DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint",
      "Arjun.swagger-viewer",
      "bierner.markdown-checkbox",
      "bierner.markdown-mermaid",
      "christian-kohler.path-intellisense",
      "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
      "eamodio.gitlens",
      "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
      "FredJeck.fav",
      "markvincze.code-fragments",
      "mhutchie.git-graph",
      "mikeburgh.xml-format",
      "ms-vscode.js-debug",
      "ms-vscode.references-view",
      "ms-vscode.vscode-js-profile-table",
      "ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare",
      "redhat.vscode-yaml",
      "telesoho.vscode-markdown-paste-image",
      "vespa-dev-works.jestRunIt",
      "VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: the project the current file is in has no knowledge of the other projects in the MR Workspace, so the Language Server will not scan these other project folders, they have nothing to do with the current project, it does not depend on them

Comment: if you do a workspace search for `authorize(` you will find all occurrences in all folder projects, there is a way to feed the search box of the search bar, some extension should be there to do it.

Comment: @rioV8 That's pretty dirty to do a search in the entire workspace to get reference even if I start being used to the Ctrl + C + Ctrl + Shift + F ...  I would love to have a direct reference list as most IDE can do

Comment: what do you think that the language server needs to do: search the whole workspace, if this editor does not what you want, write an extension that does what you want or use a different IDE

Comment: Not sure that they will allow me to spend some time writing this kind of extension but I could add it to the pile of project I wanna do somedays ^^ But that was the point, looking for a native or extension way to do a cross-folder reference search.

Comment: what will you gain instead of using the `Ctrl+Shift+F`, you have to build an AST, bla, bla, bla: a lot of work, the number of false negatives if low

Comment: @rioV8 Me personnaly, nothing. I'm used to it and I'm fine with that. Just trying to fulfill my team complaints ;)